# Slack block ui kit - Having two static selects in one row with slack modals

Tags: slack-block-kit

If you check the Google's calendar slack app, it seems that the selected block elements are rendered differently from the ones we can get from the block UI kit.

[Google's calendar slack app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWem.png)

[Slack Block UI Kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QPUr.png)

As you see in the screenshots, the only way to have two select boxes on the same row, is by using the "actions" block. But doing that

- The height of those select boxes is shorter than the one from staticSelect (input block)
- there is no option to add a label on top of every select box

But it seems that the Google's calendar app, somehow is doing that properly ... is there any other element or option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dropping a mail to *Slack*.

**Being a vendor partner**, may be **Google** have access to documentation not available to general public.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Slack and this is what they said:

> Unfortunately, these block elements seem custom made for the Google Calendar app and is not available for public use.